# using Twice the same FK in the same table with laravel

Tags: php, laravel, foreign-keys

I have a form/DB where i have to use the same fk twice but with

I get this message and really don't know how to do it

> PDOException::("SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1452 Cannot add or update a child 
>           row: a foreign key constraint fails (`Names`.`clients`, CONSTRAINT `names_try_id_foreign` FOREIGN KEY 
>           (`names_try_id`) REFERENCES `names` (`id`))").

Basically i tried to use

```
$table->foreign('name_id')->references('id')->on('names');
$table->foreign('name_try_id')->references('id')->on('names');
```

Laravel doesn't let me use

```
->references('id')->on('names');
```

twice (i think)

Comment: "REFERENCES genders" Where does genders come from?

Comment: a mistake. It is supposed to be names

Answer (score 0):

Found. A problem in one of my var names

Comment: Can you explain more please. I have same problem when I add record like your fk.